# How to connect to facebook from my application

Tags: android

I'm developing android app and i want user to connect Facebook when he open the app for the first time using Facebook SDK.
Then i want to post to the Facebook wall with specific  message from my app. I try to use Facebook sdk with my app.I have made integration between mp app and Facebook sdk but i don't know how to do the task that log in to Facebook and post to the wall with the specific message.I search stackoverflow for this task and i found this code but i can't understand it
and it doesn't for me

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Facebook facebookClient;    
    SharedPreferences mPrefs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        facebookClient=new Facebook("fb_App_id");
          ImageButton facebookButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_FacebookShare);
            facebookButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    loginToFacebook();

                    if (facebookClient.isSessionValid()) {
                        postToWall();
                    }
                }
            });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        facebookClient.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    public void loginToFacebook() {
        mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
        long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

        if (access_token != null) {
            facebookClient.setAccessToken(access_token);
        }

        if (expires != 0) {
            facebookClient.setAccessExpires(expires);
        }

        if (!facebookClient.isSessionValid()) {
            facebookClient.authorize(this, new String[] { "publish_stream" }, new DialogListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // Function to handle cancel event
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                    // Function to handle complete event
                    // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                    editor.putString("access_token", facebookClient.getAccessToken());
                    editor.putLong("access_expires", facebookClient.getAccessExpires());
                    editor.commit();

                    postToWall();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(DialogError error) {
                    // Function to handle error

                }

                @Override
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                    // Function to handle Facebook errors

                }

            });
        }
    }

    private void postToWall() {
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("name", "Battery Monitor");
        parameters.putString("link", "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ck.batterymonitor");
        parameters.putString("picture", "link to the picture");
        parameters.putString("display", "page");
        // parameters.putString("app_id", "228476323938322");

        facebookClient.dialog(MainActivity.this, "feed", parameters, new DialogListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Facebook Integration - Predefined Wall Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237980/android-facebook-integration-predefined-wall-post)

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to the following question on SO.
[Facebook login and post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237980/android-facebook-integration-predefined-wall-post?rq=1)
This code works. It will definitely solve your problem.

Comment: i use the code in this link and add the classes but when i run in emulator i get the following                                                              failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.attributionidprovider.  then i want to know where to put app_id and key hash in my app

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Android Simple Facebook (https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook) - it's a layer to make the usage of Facebook SDK easier. According to the documentation, the login process would be something like this:

Initialize callback listener:

```
OnLoginListener onLoginListener = new OnLoginListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLogin() {
        // change the state of the button or do whatever you want
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotAcceptingPermissions(Permission.Type type) {
        // user didn't accept READ or WRITE permission
        Log.w(TAG, String.format("You didn't accept %s permissions", type.name()));
    }

    /* 
     * You can override other methods here: 
     * onThinking(), onFail(String reason), onException(Throwable throwable)
     */ 
};
```

Login:

```
mSimpleFacebook.login(onLoginListener);
```